# Tool for construction of graph with specified properties

Tags: graph-theory, computer-algebra-systems

Is there a tool (class of algorithms for graph generation) that can construct graph with specified properties. E.g. construct graph who is homeomorphic with both to K5 and K3,3. Construct planar graph with n vertices whose complement is planar too.

I imagine that such tool can be combination both of library of algorithms and ontology of notable graphs and facts about graphs. I guess it could be nightmare for academic education, but lot of practical application can require such tool.

Maybe there is ongoing open source project where we can contribute?

Answer (score 1):

Listing few opensource solutions:

1. [Sagemath](http://sagemath.org) can be used to analyse [graphs](http://wiki.sagemath.org/graph)
2. [GraphTea](http://www.graphtheorysoftware.com/)

.... and [much more](http://wiki.sagemath.org/graph_survey#Existing_Graph_Theory_software)